# Exim spam centos, how can i detect the source

Tags: centos, spam, exim

i have a lot of message like this

> 2012-10-03 06:53:36 1TJGxf-0006kG-F0 ** *****@yahoo.com.tw F=<***@***.*>  R=enforce_mail_permissions: Domain .* has exceeded the max emails per hour (250/200 (125%)) allowed.  Message discarded.

I have never seen the yahoo mail of course, and there is approximately 10 messages like this every 5-10 seconds...

How could i detect the source ?

How could i stop it ?

Comment: Without a valid bounce, there isn't any way, short of finding out where the Yahoo admins live.  That's probably also a prerequisite for asking them to stop it.  Worth trying.

Comment: Is there anyway to trace the sending user at least ?

Comment: It's strange in my exim logs i have "cwd=/home/exim" as a source what does it mean, since i don't have any script there...i mean it's a folder not a file!

Comment: It just means Exim is running in that folder, just like it should.  Spammers are free to forge a message from you, it's just that most sites will ignore the forged messages, or at the very least not send backscatter to an innocent forgery victim to add insult to injury (or is it the other way around, in this case?).  You may be able to reduce the exposure somewhat by setting up proper SPF and/or DKIM records for your domain, as that helps recipient spot and block forgeries; but many receiving sites still don't check SPF and DKIM.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a programming question; voting to move to Serverfault.com.

Comment: But is there anyway to track the source and delete it...it means somebody have a script php/... somewhere and use mail function right ? so i should be able to track that ?

Comment: More likely the email is sent from a different system altogether and just forged a sender in your domain. If your Exim log shows connections from your system to Yahoo, then of course that is a different issue altogether; but I infer that you have no such indicators.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the mail queue id is 1TJGxf-0006kG-F0.  The first thing you want to do is look at the logs for that email.  There are two possible ways, depending upon how exim is configured.  Try this first:

`exim -Mvl 1TJGxf-0006kG-F0`

It will print out the logs for that email, including what IP address it came from, if there was any user who authenticated, etc.  Exim can be configured not to track this individual message information and we don't know how your exim is configured, so if that doesn't work, then run this instead:

`exigrep 1TJGxf-0006kG-F0 /var/log/exim/main.log`

You may have to find which log file your exim is logging to.  Here is how I would find that on my system:

`# exim -bP | grep log_file_path
log_file_path = /var/log/exim/%s.log`

Then use that result to figure out where your logfile is.

Having given you those tools to dig and find your info, I strongly suspect that you are running some website that has a submission form that is insecure.  By "insecure", I mean that some web bot is able to submit a sender, a recipient, and a message body and is using that form to send out massive amounts of spam.  The logs above will probably confirm that it's originating from your web server and not from somewhere outside.  Of course, it could also be some user account that is compromised because they used a spectacularly simple password of "12345" or "secret" and spam bots are connecting to that account from all over the world and using it to send out spam.

The first step is identifying the source of the spam (local web form, compromised account, etc) and then blocking that.